# Binding to asynchronous property in a template

Tags: angular

I am moving a project from a beta version to RC6. I'm trying to tie a property in my controller to a content editable directive like this:

```
<h4 contenteditable="true" [(contenteditableModel)] = "person.name" placeholder="First Last" (contenteditableModelChange)="updated($event)"></h4>
```

The `person` however is coming from a rest api so it is asynchronous. Which is causing Angular to throw an error

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'self.context.person.name')
```

That makes sense (even though this was working in the earlier code.) I've tried using the `?.` operator but then I get this error:

```
The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment
```

I am initializing the `person` object like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.forEach(params => {
        this.nodeID = params['id'];
        this.personService.getPerson(this.nodeID)
        .subscribe(person => {this.person = person});

    });
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a way to go:

```
<h4 *ngIf="person" contenteditable="true" [(contenteditableModel)] = "person.name" placeholder="First Last" (contenteditableModelChange)="updated($event)">
</h4>
```

Do not create that element if it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `()` to handle the onchange event, it may be that the "banana-box" format `[()]` is unnecessary, and causing the problem. Try just using square brackets:

```
<h4 contenteditable="true" [contenteditableModel]="person?.name" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks @nickspoon - it turns out I really needed the two-way binding, but I appreciate the answer.